# Elastic search term aggregation

Tags: python, sql, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I am writing a python script to get unique values in the elasticsearch index. I am using term aggregation to get the unique values and their counts. However when I pass a list of fields to the script I realized some of the fields are stored as

```
"abc" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        }
```

and some are stored as

```
"xyz" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
```

During term aggregation I use the query

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "abc" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "abc"
            }
        }
    }, "size":0
}
```

But when this query is used on "xyz" it gives error `Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [description] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.`

To run the query for "xyz" I need to add ".keyword" to it but then "abc" won't run.

Is there any way in which I can check which field belongs to which type and then using if/else update the query accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have both -- the field being aggregatable and searchable w/o the `.keyword` notation. Simply adjust your mapping as the error msg suggests:

```
"xyz" : {
   "type" : "text",
   "fielddata": true
}
```

then reindex & you're good to go.

As to whether there's a query-time check to determine which fields are which -- there's none. One of the core principles of ElasticSearch is that field types are predetermined and defined so that they're indexed appropriately so that the search/aggregations are optimized. Thus it's assumed at query time that you know which fields are of which type.

Comment: Hey @Joe, thanks for your response. However I can't change the structure of the index. That's why I am looking for solutions where I can compare.

Comment: Right. Then have a look at `GET your_index_name/_mapping` where all these fields' definitions are stored. Construct your queries accordingly.

Comment: Sure. Let me know how it went.